# Irregular convex quadrilateral: Find the diagonal length given all sides and one angle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, polygons, quadrilateral

I stumbled into an Irregular convex quadrilateral in one of my projects and I cannot figure out if the diagonal |BD| can be found.

**Problem**:

I have an Irregular convex quadrilateral ABCD defined by the picture as [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWLL2.png
where I know all sides |AB|, |BC|, |CD| and |DA| and angle $\angle ADC$ (inside angle of point D = $\delta$). I need to find the length of diagonal |BD|.

**Attempts**:

I have found the length of |AC| diagonal by the law of cosines:
$$ |AC|^2 = |DA|^2 + |CD|^2 - 2\cdot |DA|\cdot |CD| \cdot \cos(\delta) $$
but I cannot seem to figure out the |BD| diagonal. I tried using the area of quadrilateral or law of sines but to no avail...

Does anybody have any ideas on how to proceed?

Thank you!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3961983/finding-diagonals-in-a-quadrilateral

Comment: I really didn't see this question was posted... and I was looking for it for a while... Thank you!

Comment: You can also compute the other diagonal by calculating the area of ABC and ACD triangles and then using the area of the quadrilateral equation: $K = \sqrt{4p^2q^2-(a^2+c^2-b^2-d^2)}/4$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You found $AC$ using the cosine rule. With another version of that same law it is possible to find any angle given all three sides of a triangle. You now know all three sides of $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle ADC$. With that you can derive $\angle DAC$ and $\angle CAB$, hence $\angle DAB$.

Now, consider $\triangle DAB$. You have sides $AD$ and $AB$, and $\angle DAB$. Use the cosine rule once more to solve for $BD$.